# Multiple LDAP servers

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap, users

I have two OpenLDAP servers:

- the server A with Linux VMs a1 and a2 connected to it (PAM LDAP)
- the server B with Linux VMs b1 and b2 connected to it (PAM LDAP)

The servers have different users stored in their directories.

Is it possible to configure the servers so that

- users stored in the server A can log in to VMs a1, a2, b1 and b2
- users stored in the server B can log in to VMs b1 and b2 but not to VMs a1 and a2

?

Please, describe the configuration if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **LDAP Sync Replication** in this case.